# What is the significance of the escape character " \ " used in multiline C macros?

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I thought whitespace effectively did not matter in C. Is this different for the preprocessor? Why do we need to use " \ " when creating multiline macros?

Comment: The preprocessor cannot know where your macro ends if it occupies more than one line (there is no `#end**` for a `#define`: it's a one-liner). The \ shows that is continues on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessor directives are terminated by a newline character, so in that context newlines are distinguished from other whitespace.

Newlines are also distinguished inside `//` comments and string literals. In both cases, line-splicing can be used to extend the lexeme, although it's not considered good style.

Equally, you can extend preprocessor lines using multiline comments, because comments are replaced with a space before preprocessing directives are recognised. That probably would also be discouraged by style guides if they thought of it.